# Count specific values that belong to the same column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I would like to ask for help I would like to count the number of records but having 2 conditions for 2 specific values only from a one single column:

Count the records first:

count(service) as contacts

```
service | state | address
service1| 1     |123
service2| 1     |321
service3| 3     |332
service1| 2     |333
service2| 2     |111
service3| 3     |333
```

1st result

```
Service | Contacts | status
service1| 1        | 1
service1| 1        | 2
service1| 1        | 3
service2| 1        | 1
service2| 1        | 2
service2| 1        | 3
```

if status = 1 and 2 then add to count else 0 (only count who's "status" is equal to 1 and 2.

Result:

Final result

```
Service  | Contacts 
Service1 | 2       
Service2 | 2
```

sorry for the confusion
Thanks for your big help

Comment: Can you add (service3, 3, 3) to the table data, and also adjust the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But i forgot to mention, the column "contacts" just came from a count(X) query.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for all major databases

```
SELECT service,
SUM(CASE WHEN status IN(1,2) THEN contacts ELSE 0 END) as Contacts
FROM (your query) as x
GROUP BY service
```

Comment: THanks! I forgot to mention, the column contacts only came from a count(query)

Answer (score 0):

```
select service,
       sum(case when status in(1,2) then contacts else 0 end) as contact_count
from MyTable
group by service
```

What this will do is evaluate each row and include the `contacts` value in the `sum` where the status is one that is required. As it is an aggregate, you need to group by the `service`

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.